# Where can I find documentation on jqPlot for Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, jqplot

I'm trying to use `jqPlot` in an angular app. But I can't find a comprehensive documentation on the options and chart types available anywhere...

I checked:

[UI.Chart](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-chart/)

[ui-chart](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-chart)

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html ?

Comment: I did see this. It seemed to be in plain jQuery. I was wondering if there's any documentation for angularJs. Because I saw some guy use ui-jq="plot" and used some options there just like that. I want to know for example how to use date for x-axis, etc.

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich - Can you add your comment as the answer so I can accept it. This is the resource I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [these](http://jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html) docs in order to understand how to use it in your JS application (no matter whatever framework you use).